# Why does this the orthogonal projection include a 1/2 factor?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I'm trying to find the matrix representation of the orthogonal projection of the subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$ that has the basis $B=(x,-x)$. I thought it was simple enough, so I just did the usual and projected the canonical basis (where $e$ is the basis vector of the subspace):

$\langle e|e_1 \rangle e = (1,-1)$; $\langle e|e_2 \rangle e = (-1,1)$

So my thought process was that the matrix representation would just be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with those vectors as its components. But the solution in the manual includes a 1/2 factor. Can someone explain why this, or why my intuition of simply making a $2 \times 2$ matrix with those vectors is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your projections of the standard basis vectors onto the line are wrong precisely because $e$ is not a unit vector. If you replace $e$ with the unit vector in the direction of $e$ i.e. $(1/\sqrt{2}) e$ then you get the right answer with your method.

For some more concrete intuition, notice that the squared distance from $(1,0)$ to $(x,-x)$ is $(x-1)^2+x^2=2x^2-2x+1$, which is minimized when $x=1/2$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Another concrete intuition: $(1,0)$ reflected on the line given by $(1,-1)$ is the vector $(0,-1)$, hence their mean $((1,0)+0,-1))/2=(1/2,-1,2)$ ist the orthogonal projection.